# Sequence of Project Deployment in Mule

Tags: deployment, mule, sequence

Does anybody know in what sequence, the mule project are loaded when the Mule starts-up?
It doesn't seem to be in alphabetical order or last updated time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the class [MuleDeploymentService](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.2/modules/launcher/src/main/java/org/mule/module/launcher/MuleDeploymentService.java), you can see the following:

```
String appString = (String) options.get("app");

if (appString == null)
{
    String[] explodedApps = appsDir.list(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
    String[] packagedApps = appsDir.list(ZIP_APPS_FILTER);

    deployPackedApps(packagedApps);
    deployExplodedApps(explodedApps);
}
else
{
    String[] apps = appString.split(":");
```

[Description for method File.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) states that "there is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order". So, I guess the answer is in no particular order, or in the order they are listed in using the -app option.